# Neural Network Developing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

I am try to write a neural network class but I don't fully understand some aspects of it. I have two questions on the folling design.

[image: I have developed Neural Netowrk Design like this]

1. Am I doing this correctly? Does the bias neuron need to connect to all of neurons (except those in the input layer) or just those in the hidden layer?
2. My second question is about calculation the output value. I'm using the equation below to calculate the output value of the neurons.

   ```
   HiddenLayerFirstNeuron.Value = 
   (input1.Value * weight) + (input2.Value * weight) + (Bias.Value * weight)
   ```

   After this equation, I'm calculating the activation and the result send the output. And output neurons doing same.

I'm not sure what I am do and I want to clear up problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/contents.html in theano. This explains everything you need to know for multi layer perceptron using theano (symbolic mathematic library).

Answer (score 0):

1. The bias is usually connected to all hidden and output units.
2. Yes, you compute the input of activation function like summation of weight*output of previous layer neuron.

Good luck with development ;)

Comment: Sorry but I'm asking for to clarify; 
I must use Activation Function for all units except the Input Units?

Comment: Yes. I once use activation function(sigmoid) on input units and net perform well, but outputs of output units were low because normalized data were normalized again because of activation function of input units.

Answer (score 0):

1. There should be a separate bias neuron for each hidden and the output layer. Think of the layers as a function applied to a first order polynomials such as `f(m*x+b)=y` where `y` is your output and `f(x)` your activation function. If you look at the the linear term you will recognize the `b`. This represents the bias and it behaves similar with neural network as with this simplification: It shifts the hyperplane up and down the in the space. Keep in mind that you will have one bias per layer connected to all neurons of that layer `f((wi*xi+b)+...+(wn*xn+b))` with an initial value of 1. When it comes to gradient descent, you will have to train this neuron like a normal weight.
2. In my opinion should you apply the activation function to the output layer as well. This is how it's usually done with multilayer perceptrons. But it actually depends of what you want. If you, for example, use the logistic function as activation function and you want an output in the interval `(0,1)`, then you have to apply your activation function to the output as well. Since a basic linear combination, as it is in your example, can theoretically go above the boundaries of the previously mentioned Intervall.